# How to extract specified character string from string

Tags: c, string

```
char string[]="DGS021J0W0S1000.0S20000S3000.0S4000.0S50.00S60.00F";
```

how to get `S[1-5]`
thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: hint extract every character from the string and compare it with the needed character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for substring methods.
You can do it in two for loops in C.

Answer (score 3):

Use [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) standard function

```
char S[6] = {0};
strncpy(S, string+1 , 5);
```

If you want to copy from the beginning of the string to the 5th charachter, then your question should be

> how to get S[0-4]

and not `S[1-5]` because array index in C start from 0 and not from 1. and the solution for this case will be

```
char S[6] = {0};
strncpy(S, string , 5);
```